# Trouble converting UTM to lat long for southern hemisphere

Tags: latitude-longitude, coordinate-transformation, utm

I have ~40 points in UTM zone 19 taken from Peru that I would like to convert to lat/long to project onto Google Earth. I am having some problems with PBSmapping and can't seem to figure out the solution. I have searched through the forums and tried several different methods, including the project command in proj4 but still can't get this to work. Here is the code I have currently written

```
library(PBSmapping)
#just two example UTM coordinates
data<-as.data.frame(matrix(c(214012,197036,8545520,8567292),nrow=2))
attr(data,"projection") <- "UTM"
attr(data, "zone") <- 19
colnames(data)<-c("X","Y")
convUL(data,km=FALSE)
```

The corresponding lat/longs should be somewhere with lats between -12.9XXXXX and -13.0XXXXX and long between -71.8XXXX to -71.4XXXX. The values given by convUL seem to be way off.

Comment: It seems that these may not be valid UTM coordinates for Peru. At least not for the usual reference systems EPSG 24892 and EPSG 24893. Could you check for that?

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the valid pairs of coordinates you could do something like this:

```
library(rgdal)
data <- data.frame(id = c(1:2), x = c(214012,197036) , y = c(8545520,8567292))
coordinates(data) = ~x+y
```

Asign projection

```
# Use the appropriate EPSG Code
proj4string(data) = CRS('+init=epsg:24891') # 24891 or 24893
```

Transform to geographic coordinates
`enter code here`data_wgs84 <- spTransform(data, CRS('+init=epsg:4326'))

Get some valid background data to plot it against

```
# Country data
package(dismo)
peru <-getData('GADM', country='PER', level=0)
plot(peru, axes = T)
plot(data, add = T)
```

Write your KML file

```
# Export kml
tmpd <- 'D:\\'
writeOGR(data_wgs84, paste(tmpd, "peru_data.kml", sep="/"), 'id', driver="KML")
```